# Iterate through an array of dictionaries in a Django Template

Tags: python, django

How can I iterate through an array of dictionaries in a Django Template?

```
data = [{'name' : 'Bob', 'age' : 20}, {'name': 'Sally', 'age' : 20}]
```

I'm having trouble with this code from the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#for) because of the array

```
{% for key, value in data.items %}
    {{ key }}: {{ value }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`items` doesn't work because you are calling it on the list, but you don't need to do that either. As you have the same keys in your dictionaries, just loop over the list and access the dictionary directly:

```
{% for item in foo %}
   {{ item.name }}
   {{ item.age }}
{% endfor %}
```

The [documentation on template variables](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/templates/#variables) explains how/why the `.` works when it comes to dictionaries:

> Technically, when the template system encounters a dot, it tries the
>   following lookups, in this order:
>
> - Dictionary lookup
> - Attribute lookup
> - Method call
> - List-index lookup

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your loop is iterating over the list, not the dict. You might try a nested loop.

```
{% for details in data %}
    {% for key, value in details.items %}
        {{ key }}: {{ value }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Since it looks like your dicts have the same keys, you may also do something like:

```
{% for details in data %}
    name: {{ details.name }}
    age: {{ details.age }}
{ % endfor %}
```

If you have larger dicts or dynamic keys, then you're probably better off using nested loops.